# Count how many ID (fk) there are, where ID (fk) is the same, but column value != given value

Tags: sql

Lets say I have a table 'trips' with a class id, which is a foreign key into another table 'classes', and a column 'trip' which is just text.

```
62 'Zoo'
62 'Park'
62 'Observatory'
64 'Park'
64 'Zoo'
81 'Park'
```

I want to count how many classes there are that did not go to the Observatory.
How do I got about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is aggregation:

```
select class
from trips t
group by class
having sum(case when trip = 'Observatory' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

If you have a table of classes (which you probably do), use `not exists`:

```
select c.*
from classes c
where not exists (select 1
                  from trips t
                  where t.classid = c.classid and
                        t.trip = 'Observatory'
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Count the classes, count the number of classes that went to the observatory, subtract:

```
WITH cteTotal_class_count AS (SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_CLASS_COUNT
                                FROM CLASSES),
     cteObservatory_class_count AS (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CLASS_ID) AS OBSERVATORY_CLASS_COUNT
                                      FROM TRIPS
                                      WHERE UPPER(TRIP) = 'OBSERVATORY')
SELECT TOTAL_CLASS_COUNT - OBSERVATORY_CLASS_COUNT AS COUNT_OF_CLASSES_WHO_DIDNT_GO
  FROM cteTotal_class_count
  CROSS JOIN cteObservatory_class_count
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a6393aa52badf8c22a0cc85b90b9273e)

Answer (score 0):

Same idea of the previous answer, but a bit simplified:

```
SELECT (SELECT count(distinct class_id) FROM trips) - 
       (SELECT count(distinct class_id) FROM trips WHERE trip = 'Observatory');
```